# React Native: How to disable navigator sceneconfig gestures on the fly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, swipe, gesture, navigator

I know it's possible to disable the scene gesture when pushing the scene with a sceneconfig where gestures are null like so:

```
return {
  ...CustomNavigatorSceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom,
  gestures: {}
};
```

But I'd like to temporarily disable the gesture when the view is already pushed.

I have a lightbox/image modal with zoom support. When the image is zoomed-in I need to disable the swipe gesture as it will otherwise activate when the user is panning the image. But by default and zoomed-out I want the gesture to work.

Is it possible to disable the sceneconfig gesture on the fly - like in response to the current state?

My workaround right now is to handle the gesture logic inside the view instead (with panresponder/scrollview events) but since navigator routes aren't transparent ([#4494](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4494)) it's not possible to replicate the default animation/gesture this way.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @PeterGerhat Unfortunately not. I've moved to NavigationExperimental since though, which allows transparent routes so you can handle all the gesture logic inside the view instead if you're after the lightbox/image gesture.